# passing a variable with option as a parameter in perl script

Tags: python

I have a comment in a variable as follows

```
i_desc = request.POST.get('desc').
```

Here i will get a description(like small comment) in this variable now I need to pass this variable as a parameter in perl script as follows:

```
args_str1 = "flexiserver/build/svnenv.sh -j 'svntasktag.pl -u i_uname -a i_passw  -c "%i_desc%" ss_fvnteste'"
```

In the log I am getting following error

```
File "/var/fpwork/sudhb/pai_dashboard_BLR/site/pai_app/classviews/tagview.py", line 70, in post
    args_str1 = "flexiserver/build/svnenv.sh -j 'svntasktag.pl -u i_uname -a i_passw  -c "%i_desc%" ss_fvnteste'"
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Can anyone please help in this

Comment: This doesn't sound like a standard Perl error. Grep your source code or libraries in use for the message.

Comment: its not a perl error. actually its a django project in this in a function i ma using one perl script through some parameters. one of the parameter is "-c" which means a comment I am getting a comment value in the varibale but i have to replace the value of the variable after "-c" option. normally in perl script we will use like \"<string value>\". Now here i need to get the string value through variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for something like this, which is one of several ways of embedding variables in strings, using Python.

Interactively in the Python console:

```
>>> i_desc = "your_string"
>>> args_str1 = "flexiserver/build/svnenv.sh -j 'svntasktag.pl -u i_uname -a i_passw  -c \"{}\" ss_fvnteste'".format(i_desc)
>>> args_str1
'flexiserver/build/svnenv.sh -j \'svntasktag.pl -u i_uname -a i_passw  -c "your_string" ss_fvnteste\''
```